# Storyboard Segue to Multiple Views?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard

I am setting up a bunch of view controllers in my storyboard and have a 'Next' button.

I need this to segue to two different view however my storyboard won't allow it. For example if certain criteria are met the next button will go to one view, if not, it will go to the other view.

Any help much appreciate achieving this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to create the two segues from your view controller, not from the button. In the storyboard, control-drag from the view controller to where you want the segue to go. Repeat for the other segue. Click on each segue and give them unique identifiers (for this demo I'll use "segue1" and "segue2").

Then, go to your ViewController that initiated the segues. You need to set an action up for your button.

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender{
   if(criteria met){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:self];
     }
   else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue2" sender:self];
   }
 }
```

Sender is self in this case because it is the view controller causing the segue, not the button directly.  You will also need to implement prepareForSegue.