# InstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier CRASH (Xcode 4)

Tags: xcode4, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I've been experiencing crashes in trying to load my CafesViewController. I have all the identifiers I know of in file inspector set to CafesViewController, and also checked "Use storyboard ID."

My main menu View loads perfectly because it is defined as the default storyboard in my plist, however, there is a disconnect in loading the Cafes option when the button is pressed to load my Cafes listing (my app is a city directory of things to do).

My current code is:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([mlabel.text isEqualToString: @" Cafés " ])
    {        
    UIStoryboard *cafesViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    cafesViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CafesViewController"];
    }
}
```

If someone can offer input, I would greatly appreciate it as I don't know where the disconnect is. The error, of course, reads "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'CafesViewController'

I'm thinking my call to action is wrong, but can someone give me their input?

Thank you!

Comment: There are a couple of problems here.  One is that the `destinationViewController` is a view controller and therefore can't be a `UIStoryboard`.  (I would have thought the compiler would flag that!)  The bigger one, though, is that when `prepareForSegue:` is called, you're already in the middle of having a new view controller being activated, so instantiating yet another controller just seems like a wrong idea.

Comment: Thank you Phillip! I've amended the version to read like this, but not sure if this works:

Comment: if ([mlabel.text isEqualToString: @" Cafés " ])
    {
        UIStoryboard *cafes = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Cafes" bundle:nil];
       UIViewController *CafesViewController = [cafes instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self presentViewController:CafesViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

Comment: This is tough, because you are right that my main storyboard is already activated and here I am trying to begin another with an IF statement, but I'm not sure what else to do because I have multiple storyboards to be activated with a single button with those IF statements. I wonder if this is even possible...

Comment: Do you think that all my views should be attached to ONE storyboard?

Comment: I haven't yet found a use for multiple storyboards except for multiple device-type support in universal apps.  (There may **be** other reasons; I just haven't needed it.)  Mostly, people use a single storyboard as a dumb container for view controllers and have the program logic deal with controller interactions.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, Phillip. I found a great answer here as well that solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073662/storyboard-segue-to-multiple-views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my question with the following simple code:

```
-(void)mainButton
{
  if ([mlabel.text isEqualToString: @" Arts " ])
  {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Arts" sender:self];
  }
}
```

In research, I learned that I could do what I wanted simply through the sample with the button specified above, rather than PrepareForSegue. Very easy.